# How do I prevent git on Cygwin to set core.filemode=true

Tags: git, cygwin

I am using git from a Cygwin installation on my Windows PC. Although cygwin supports the Unix permission bits on an NTFS file system, native Windows programs like my Eclipse don't know about them so that all files created by Windows programs have the executable bit set (`755`).

I only rarely ever need to check in a file with executable bit set into a Git repository. Therefore, I would like to have `core.filemode=false` by default. I set this value in my global configuration, but unfortunately this typically has no effect: as [documented](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), `git clone` probes the file system to see if it supports permissions and sets the `core.filemode` accordingly *per repository*, and therefore I have a `core.filemode=true` configuration in every repository configuration, overriding my desired default.

Is there a way to prevent `git clone` from setting `core.filemode` automatically?

Comment: In case this is relevant: I'm using git version 1.7.9

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Bash such that each time you `cd` it checks if that directory is a repository and sets it up properly. In your `~/.bash_profile` add

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND=pc
pc () {
  [ -d .git -a ! -g .git/config ] || return
  git config core.filemode 0
  chmod +s .git/config
}
```

Comment: It is good to see that you keep improving your answer. And that even though you seem to no longer like the question...

Answer (score 1):

The `core.fileMode = true` setting can be cleared automatically using a [git hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).  In this case I believe a post-checkout hook, which will run anytime a branch is checked out or a repo is cloned, is the best option.  Create bash script named `post-checkout` (no file extension) with the following contents:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

core_file_mode=$( git config --local core.fileMode )

if [[ "${OSTYPE}" == 'cygwin' && "${core_file_mode}" == 'true' ]]; then
    git config --local --unset core.fileMode
fi
```

If you want the hook to be applied to an individual repo put the script in `$GIT_DIR/hooks` (by default `$GIT_DIR` is `<path-to-your-repo>/.git`).  If want the hook to apply to all projects add the following entry to your global gitconfig file:

```
[core]
    hooksPath = '<path-to-folder-containing-your-hook(s)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to init or clone your repo using a git template directory.

```
 git clone --template=<template directory>
```

In that directory, you can specify a config file, which will be used as a *local* git repo config for the newly init'd or cloned repo.

The [OP oberlies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523648/oberlies) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457910/how-do-i-prevent-git-on-cygwin-to-set-core-filemode-true/12458548#comment19021021_12458548) though that it won't work for `core.filemode` and `core.ignorecase`, for [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html):

> [`git-clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone.html) or [`git-init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init.html) will probe and set `core.fileMode` false if appropriate when the repository is created.

Comment: This doesn't work: both `git clone` and `git init` overwrite the `core.filemode` value from the config template.

Comment: @oberlies whoa, two months laters ;) Ok. What is the version of git in your Cygwin? Any chance to try it with an msysgit, outside of Cygwin? Because according to the doc or to http://monkeypatch.me/blog/mixing-professional-and-personal-git-configurations.html, `config` shouldn't be overridden.

Comment: It is possible to set other configuration properties through a `config` file in the template, but git overwrites the `core.filemode` and `core.ignorecase` values from the template. I seems that [git is just trying to be too smart](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#_variables)...

Comment: @oberlies interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.